# Allow my app to be 'share gate' for other apps

Tags: android

I want my app to be able to share other apps content by text/links, from a youtube link to a instagram picture, to a facebook post, etc. Whenever the user opens the menu "share via" I want my app to appear in the menu and them obtain the information via text and use it accordingly. I tried adding this in the activity of interest but noticed it won't work...

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>
```

So, how exactly should this be done so it works for all apps that can provide this sort of content and how can I handle the links to the respective apps after?

Comment: "I tried adding this in the activity of interest but noticed it won't work..." -- that is because `ACTION_SEND` does not use `Uri` values, and so `<data>` elements will eliminate you from `ACTION_SEND` requests.

Comment: @CommonsWare I could use a practical example on your response please.

Comment: Remove the data elements from your intent filter and see what happens.

Comment: @ci_ literally nothing, app still doesn't show in the "share" fragment inside other apps